# HTML contenteditable works when tabbed into but not when clicked into

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I want to have a `span` content editable so I've added the `contentEditable ="true"` attribute to the span element but it is only editable if I tab into the field with the keyboard, but if I click on the text with the mouse cursor it's not editable. I thought there might be some event listener doing something funky so I did a nasty hack to override the onclick and onfocus events to do nothing and not propagate to ancestor event listeners

```
<span 
    onclick="javascript:return false;" 
    onfocus="javascript:return false;"  
    contentEditable ="true">Edit Me</span>
```

As an example for it not working the title `Gold Coast Waters 3 Day Forecast` should be editable on the following page:
[Non-Working Example](http://preview.test.coastwatch.com.au/3-day-forecast?region=GoldCoastWaters)

The fiddle below for `contenteditable` works so there is something in my code that is preventing this from working and I can't seem to narrow down what it is.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <span contenteditable="true">Hello World</span>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Any ideas on what is preventing the editing when I click on the `span`?

Comment: Why do you have: `onclick="javascript:return false;" 
    onfocus="javascript:return false;"`?

Comment: Both versions of the code you are showing work. And, since you're showing code where it works, then clearly you have another issue somewhere else, but you didn't post any other code, so how are we supposed to help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code shown as not working works and no other code was provided.

Comment: @Scott Marcus I've added an example of where it is not working in the `Non-Working Example` link. The

Comment: OK, i just understand that you want to fix a bug and not to build a feature. Why din't use the word "bug" ?
It should be more clear for every one ( i use google translate)

Comment: You have too many error on your page, see that = https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fpreview.test.coastwatch.com.au%2F3-day-forecast%3Fregion%3DGoldCoastWaters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `$(".sortable").disableSelection()` is a bit nasty and stops elements with `contenteditable="true"` on them from being editable. I removed that line from my code and elements are now editable.

Also, use of that function is discouraged by jQuery:  http://api.jqueryui.com/disableselection/